# Shipping a kayak to India - or can I fly with it?

Tags: shipping, sport-equipment, canoeing-and-kayaking

I've a trip planned to India in May and was wondering whether it would be possible to ship my kayak (non-inflatable) from the States to India and back. I would like to find out the best way to do it which would be cost effective and easy on the kayak itself.

I don't think I'll be allowed to use a commercial airline to move it, so I'm looking at other options. If any one has done this in the past and knows an airline from the US to India which does this, that would be useful.

I'm adding the dimensions of my equipment:
132 x 31 x 18 inches, 45 pounds.

Comment: *I don't think I'll be allowed to use a commercial airline to move it*.  Did you research this?  All my transatlantic flights to date have been with Icelandair which does take kayaks (for a considerable fee).  They don't fly to India but if one carrier takes them, it's worth checking if others do, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things I'd never thought I'd ask: "How big is your kayak?"

With Emirates Airlines, you can send sports equipment as luggage so long as its length+height+width is less than 300cm, for $350 each way.  They also have an air-cargo service for larger items.

300cm seems small to me and $700 a lot of money.  Maybe just buy a kayak in India and abandon it or resell it when you leave?

See [here](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/carry-kayak-airline-105782.html) for some suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Quite a few airlines will take kayaks as checked baggage.  But it is not cheap to do and not all kayaks are accepted (sea kayaks are often too long, whereas white water squirt boats are not).  Plus you need to take into consideration when booking your flights, what planes you are ticketed on, since smaller commuter jets or prop planes might not have a big enough cargo bay to accommodate your boat.